# Fokker-Planck equation for 2D SDE

Tags: probability, differential-equations, diffusion, stochastic-processes

Consider the following two-dimensional SDE
\begin{align*}
\mathrm{d}\mathbf{X}(t) &=  {\mathbf{f}(\mathbf{X}(t))}\mathrm{d}t+\mathrm{d}\mathbf{W}(t)\\
\end{align*}
where $\mathbf{X}(t)=\begin{bmatrix}X_1(t)\\X_2(t)\end{bmatrix}$, the drift is given by $\mathbf{f}(\mathbf{X})=\begin{bmatrix}f_1(\mathbf{X})\\ f_2(\mathbf{X}) \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}\frac{1}{1+X_2(t)}+X_1(t)\\\frac{1}{1+X_1(t)}+X_2(t)\end{bmatrix}$, and $\mathbf{W}(t)$ is a two-dimensional standard Wiener processes.

By interpreting the above system in the Itô sense, the probability distribution  $\rho(\mathbf{x})$ for $\mathbf{X}(t)$, evolves according to a Fokker-Planck equation:
$$
\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial t} = \left[-\sum_{i=1}^2 \frac{\partial }{\partial x_i}f_i \rho + \sum_{i=1}^2\sum_{j=1}^2 \frac{\partial^2 }{\partial x_i \partial x_j}  \rho\right]
$$

Since, in this case, the drift $\mathbf{f}$ does not satisfy the so-called "potential conditions", I don't think it is possibile to find a closed-form expression of the steady-state probability distribution $\rho$.

> However, it is possibile to find a "good" approximation of the steady-state probability distribution?

Any comment is welcome (pointers to the literature are also appreciated). Thanks!

Comment: Note: I believe the $f_i$ in the diffusion term is incorrect. When translating between SDE and FPE, the diffusion term in the FPE is given as the square of the function that comes with the Wiener-process in the SDE: $B(X)dW \to \partial^2(B^2\rho)$

Comment: @Nephente Correct, thanks! Sorry for the typo.

Comment: No problem. But more to the point, Gardiner discusses the multivariate FPE in various limits in his "Handbook of Stochastic Methods" (which you have probably already considered)

Comment: @Nephente Yes, I already took a quick look at Sec. 6 of Gardiner's book. However, I couldn't find any result for the large diffusivity regime (which is the case I'm interested the most).